# Ошибка сериализации моделей JSON

Tags: java, json, spring

Появляется вот такого рода ошибка

> Could not write JSON: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.springboot.model.User["authorities"])

Модель Role  является реализацией интерфейса GrantedAuthority.

Полагаю именно в этом загвоздка, но не совсем понимаю, что можно с этим сделать.
Может написать сериализатор кастомный, но не особо представляю, с чего начать.

Код обоих моделей ниже.

```
public class User implements UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;



public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "role_id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "role")
private String roleName;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
@JsonIgnore
List<User> users;
```

Буду благодарен за любые советы и предложения.

Сама ошибка возникает при попытке передать список пользователей на html страницу.
Если чем-то поможет, соответствующий метод в контроллере.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/admin", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public List<User> showUsersTable(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
List<User> listUsers = userService.listUsers();
return listUsers;
```

Answer (score 0):

Секрет, как очень часто и бывает - во внимательной работе с собственными классами и, в особенности, с переопределением методов.

Переписанный соответствующим образом метод getAuthorities() решил проблему.

```
@Override
public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
     List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Role role: roles) {
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName()));
        role.getPrivileges().stream()
        .map(p -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(p.getRoleName()))
        .forEach(grantedAuthorities::add);
    }
    return grantedAuthorities;
}
```

Надеюсь кому-то поможет не совершать моих глупых ошибок.